# Infer class generics when using `instanceof`

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Assuming we have the following code:

```js
class Foo<T = number> {
  foo: T;

  constructor(foo: T) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}

const F: typeof Foo<number> = Foo;

let f: unknown;

if (f instanceof F) {
  f.foo; // 'any', why is this not a 'number'?
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVaBeaA7ArgWwCMBTAJwD5oBvAKGmgDNEAuaFAbmtumHiwgBcSOYP3gkAFI3gsUASipc6-ABYBLCADopGBog50AvtSPUeffnBb8AngAci8enERJchUhUwJ4HaiCIW9Cw4WADWWPAA7li+qk6S0KrmYFjADk6w8jR09Fp60AD0BdAA5CnWJQA00JHK1okwKurY8BZuxCQA-MZAA)

Why is `f` of type `Foo<any>` and not `Foo<number>`? And can I make this work only using `instanceof` or do I have to use a [type predicates function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TobiasS. and @MuratKaragöz pointed out, the `instanceof` operator can not distinguish `Foo` and `F` at runtime, hence the generics are not passed down.

There are two paths to fixing this:

### Using instanceof only

##### Unsafe at runtime

Instead of typing `F` with `typeof Foo<number>` as I did. We can create a new constructor type which return an instance of `Foo<number>`:

```js
class Foo<T = number> {
  foo: T;

  constructor(foo: T) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}

const F: new (...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Foo<number>>) => Foo<number> = Foo

let f: unknown = new F(0)

if (f instanceof F) {
  f.foo; // number
}
```

This is a very simple way of typing `F`, but it IS unsafe at runtime because it tricks Typescript into thinking `Foo` and `F` are not the same class, even thought `(new Foo()) instanceof F` returns true at runtime (see the safer method below).

Although, this trick can still be useful in few niche cases (I personally ended up using a combination of the safe and unsafe methods).

##### Safe at runtime

This is most likely the preferred solution, as it does not suffer from the same caveat as the unsafe solution above.

Put simply, we can create a new class `F` which extends `Foo<number>`:

```
class Foo<T = number> {
  foo: T;

  constructor(foo: T) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}

class F extends Foo<number> {
  constructor(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Foo<number>>) {
    super(...args)
  }
}

let f: unknown;

if (f instanceof F) {
  f.foo; // number
}
```

This IS safer because `(new Foo()) instanceof F` will return false at runtime, on the opposite of the unsafe solution.

### Using type guards

See @TobiasS.'s and @MuratKaragöz's answers.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74626164/8990411
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74626118/8990411

Comment: Its interesting to see your first solution actually narrowing the type of `f` to `Foo<number>`. Allthough you should not trust it: https://tsplay.dev/NrDK1W. By giving `F` this type, you are just fooling the compiler into thinking that `F` is a `class` when it is not. I would consider this a bug in the compiler.

Comment: @TobiasS. True, I've made my answer clearer to explain this

Answer (score 1):

You could use typeguards e.g

```
function isF(isF: unknown): isF is Foo<number>{
  return isF instanceof F;
}

if (isF(f)) {
  f.foo; // Foo<number>
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. But still wonder if there's a way to do this only using instanceof, because it seems odd that we can't.

Comment: @AnatoleLucet As soon as you use `unknown` or `any` you are telling the tscompiler to ignore static type checking. You then have to assert the type manually.

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe to assume that `f` is of type `Foo<number>` by checking `f instanceof F`. The `instanceof` operator does not care about generics as they are erased at runtime.

We can instantiate `f` with `new Foo("a string")` without an issue. `f instance F` will return `true`, even though `f` is of type `Foo<string>`.

```
const F: typeof Foo<number> = Foo;

let f: unknown = new Foo("a string")

console.log(f instanceof F)
// true

if (f instanceof F) {
  console.log(f.foo);
  // "a string"
}
```

The *only* safe way to check if `f` is `Foo<number>` is to use a type guard which both checks if `f` is `instanceof Foo` and `typeof f.foo === "number"`.

```
const isFooNumber = (arg: unknown): arg is Foo<number> => {
  return arg instanceof Foo && typeof arg.foo === "number"
}

if (isFooNumber(f)) {
  console.log(f.foo);
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVaBeaA7ArgWwCMBTAJwD5oBvAKGmgDNEAuaFAbmtumHiwgBcSOYP3gkAFI3gsUASipc6-ABYBLCADopGBog50AvtSPUeffnBb8AngAci8enERJchUhUwJ4HaiCIW9Cw4WADWWPAA7lg6WESRzvDiAERg0AIkqlgA5smynGYQ8P4aIPDZktBZAmBYwA5OsPkA9M3QgjhEnKpOldX8tfWOcPI0dIXFRKXlklqIshwmhRbq3gBy+MQkOuJgJNnBYRHRsix72VUw3q6bHhgUY9AkATgkMedV5oMNidAAZH92nYfuc5vAMOhMMk3FtksZur1VogNu4JPRZKMuBMSmUKvQwQt4XROEA)

Comment: Definitely, but you can not instance `F` with a string. That's why it seems weird to me.

Comment: How does it seem weird to you? I demonstrated that the `instanceof` operator can *not* be used in a way that would differentiate a `Foo<number>` from any other `Foo`. We can only ensure that `f` is of some type `Foo`. The compiler will substitute `T` with `any` as there is no further information available.

Comment: To make sure that `f` is of type `Foo<number>`, you will *have to* check what the type of `foo` is using `typeof foo === "number"`.

Comment: @TobiasS. Would also be enough to actually use a constraint like `Foo<T extends number> `

Comment: I understand, you can't differentiate `F` and `Foo` at runtime, OK! But, at compile time, you can not instantiate `F` with something else than a number because of the strict(er) `typeof Foo<number>`. So it seems weird that typescript doesn't assume that `f.foo` IS a number

Comment: @TobiasS. if we go in your direction, we could assume the same for variables. Nothing will 100% guaranty that a variable is not of some other type at runtime.

Comment: I guess there's no other way than type guards, but I thought I'd ask

Comment: Yes, you can't instantiate an `F` with anything else than a number. But the `instanceof` operator does not check if `f` was instantiated with `F`. It only checks if `f` is a `Foo`.

Comment: @TobiasS. True.
That made me think about doing the following, do you see any caveat?
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVaBeaA7ArgWwCMBTAJwD5oBvAKGmgDNEAuaFAbmtumHiwgBcSOYP3gkAFI3gsUASipc6-ABYBLCADopGBog50AvtSPVQkGLGhEAHvyJYAJhcRJchUhRp0efQcNESGkFgJADmECwAwrwCQiJiAAohYHhEdiQQSPwAngAORPD0cC5uxORk8l500BA4+YHBYRCyXEYmIGkMLDhYANZY8ADuWDpYRINw4gAMLdSqRZLQqr5gWMAFRbCVXD4Q8B0aIPChklqIshwGQA

Comment: That should work, as `F` is now its own class.

Comment: Great! Many thanks for the help @ TobiasS. & MuratKaragöz